# Angular2 fire listen to node changes throws an error

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

The code below was working and it should listen for changes in a node and execute a function but now am getting an error:

```
ncaught TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
at SwitchMapSubscriber.eval [as project] (changes.js:7)
```

So, in my `angular2` component I have:

```
private subscriptions = new Subscription();

registered: AngularFireList<any>;
constructor(private _af: AngularFireDatabase){
     this.registered = _af.list('/registered');
 }

ngOnInit() {
    this.subscriptions.add(
        this.registered.valueChanges().subscribe(
            res => {
                console.log("the value has changed");
            }
        )
    );
}
```

So where am I going wrong as getting the error above which point to:

```
angular2fire/database/list/changes
```

What I need my code to do is to listen to whenever there is a change in a firebase node and log to the console

The subscriptions have also been defined by:

```
    private subscriptions = new Subscription();
```

Adding it to the subscriptions then I can use `onDestroy` lifecycle and prevent memory leaks as shown below

```
    ngOnDestroy() {
      this.subscriptions.unsubscribe();
    }
```

Comment: `subscriptions` has been defined?

Comment: yes ive already defined them , ive updated the question

Comment: I got a query here. Why are you adding it to subscription? You can just do registered.valueChanges and handle the result right? any specific reason to do so?

Comment: its so that during destroy i can unsubscribe to the changes preventing memory leaks

Comment: ive also updated the question with the onDestroy life cycle which unsubscribes any subscriptions

Comment: Ok.. makes sense.. But within the subscription, you are again subscribing.. Can you just do `return this.registered.valueChanges()`???

Comment: but the reults of this.registered.valueChanges() is an observable so youll  need to subscribe. Or how do i go about this as i would oinly like to listen for changes and then execute a function whenever changes happen

Comment: It looks like rxjs version mismatch issue.Maybe the firebase package requires newer version of rxjs

Comment: @GEOFFREYMWANGI have you seen my answer? Did it worked?

Comment: @noobs sure it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a popular issue these days. Please upgrade `rxjs 5` to version 6.

This happens due to **some breaking changes in `AngularFire`**. Once upgraded the function should perform as expected.

Upgrade using: `npm install rxjs@6 rxjs-compat@6 --save` (**Recomended**)

Or rollback (**Not recomended**) using:

```
npm uninstall angularfire2
npm install angularfire2@5.0.0-rc.4
npm uninstall firebase
npm install firebase@4.8.0
```

See the `rxjs` official [migration doc](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/docs_app/content/guide/v6/migration.md) for how-to's and more details on the changes between 5 and 6.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you don't have a list for your subscriptions, but only a single subscription stored in `subscriptions`. Try changing it to an array like this:

```
private subscriptions: Subscription[] = [];

registered: AngularFireList<any>;
constructor(private _af: AngularFireDatabase){
     this.registered = _af.list('/registered');
 }

ngOnInit() {
    this.subscriptions.push(
        this.registered.valueChanges().subscribe(
            res => {
                console.log("the value has changed");
            }
        )
    );
}

ngOnDestroy() {
   this.subscriptions.forEach((s) => s.unsubscribe());
}
```

With `Subscription.add` you actually add `TeardownLogic` to an existing subscription. This can be used when you have additional cleaning up to do.

If you know that you will only have one subscription, use the assignment operator `=` instead of the `add()` function, like this:

```
private subscription: Subscription;

registered: AngularFireList<any>;
constructor(private _af: AngularFireDatabase){
     this.registered = _af.list('/registered');
 }

ngOnInit() {
    this.subscription =
        this.registered.valueChanges().subscribe(
            res => {
                console.log("the value has changed");
            }
     );
}

ngOnDestroy() {
   this.subscription.unsubscribe();
}
```

Comment: this doesnt work, it throws even more errors like this.subscriptions.unsubscribe is not a function

Comment: If you take a look at my example, I iterate over the subscriptions list using .forEach. You can also have just one subscription and unsubscribe from it, I'll add an example in my answer.

Comment: I've added an example with a single subscription below. Please have a look at that.

Comment: You can also have a look at the answer given in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38008334/angular-rxjs-when-should-i-unsubscribe-from-subscription