# AngularFireDatabase Does not retrieve data

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

Whenever I use afDB.list('/path') method, I get the following:
[console.log(this.items);](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RtwkN.png)

and I have this example as my firebase database: [listings file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hONkG.png)

surprisingly, editing the data works perfectly fine (e.g. remove(), push(),... etc.), but I can't seem to be able to retrieve it; however, I can access it. I thought it might be a rules issue, yet, my rules are fine: [firebase Rules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7sEAP.png)

this is the portion of the code that I'm having trouble with:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import { FirebaseProvider } from '../../providers/firebase/firebase';
import { AngularFireDatabase } from 'angularfire2/database';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';

//import { ListingDetailsPage } from '../listing-details/listing-details';



@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  items: Observable<any[]>;

  constructor(
    public navCtrl: NavController,
    public afAuth: AngularFireAuth,
    public firebaseProvider: FirebaseProvider,
    public afDB: AngularFireDatabase
    ) {
    this.items = afDB.list('/listings',  ref => ref.orderByChild('age').equalTo('large')).valueChanges();
  }

 login(){
     this.afAuth.auth.signInWithPopup(new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider()).then(res => console.log(res));
 }

 logout() {
    this.afAuth.auth.signOut();
 }

 list(){
    console.log(this.items);
 }

}
```

I also tried to use AngularFireList instead of Observable, but it doesn't change the issue. I also used afDB.object() instead of afDB.list(), I still get the same problem. Query is not the issue either, as I tried to use a simple .list()/.object() and again the same issue. additionally, I created a database using the same code (.set()), and I couldn't retrieve it either.

Relevant Specs:

```
"angularfire2": "^5.0.0-rc.11",
"firebase": "^5.2.0",
"promise-polyfill": "^8.0.0",
"ionic-angular": "3.9.2",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "5.2.11",
"@angular/core": "5.2.11",
```

OS: Windows10
platforms tested: Google Chrome Browser/ Firefox Browser/ Android SDK emulator

Answer (score 0):

You've defined your `items` variable as an observable (*and that is correct*) but if you want to play with the data returned from that observable, you need to subscribe to that observable.

```
constructor(
    public navCtrl: NavController,
    public afAuth: AngularFireAuth,
    public firebaseProvider: FirebaseProvider,
    public afDB: AngularFireDatabase
) {
    this.items = afDB.list('/listings',  ref => ref.orderByChild('age').equalTo('large')).valueChanges();
    this.items.subscribe( valueOfItems => {
        console.log(valueOfItems);
    })
}
```

Comment: this solution throws an error: TypeError: Object(...) is not a function

Comment: I'd also like to add that the error was generated by polyfills.js at /www/build/polyfills.js

Answer (score 0):

There is a compatibility issue in Angularfire2 with rxjs. So, until Angularfire2 provide support for rxjs6, you can resolve this error by installing rxjs-compat package using below command.

```
npm install rxjs@6 rxjs-compat@6 --save
```

you can find more information in the rxjs migration guide. 
https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/docs_app/content/guide/v6/migration.md

Answer (score -1):

there is also a "template driven" way to retrieve data.

Template :

```
    // example 1
    <ul>
      <li *ngFor="let dino of dinosaurs$ | async">
        <p>{{vdino.name }}</p>
      </li>
    </ul>

    // example 2
    <ul>
      <li *ngFor="let dino of dinosaursArray">
        <p>{{vdino.name }}</p>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

Controller :

```
constructor(private afDb: AngularFireDatabase) {
  const itemsRef: AngularFireList<any> = afDb.list('dinosaurs');

  // example 1
  this.dinosaurs$ = itemsRef.valueChanges();

  // example 2
  this.dinosaurs$.subscribe(array => this.dinosaursArray = array);
}
```

Here a stackblitz with the two examples (credits to @markgoho) :
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-trrnhg

The deps are a bit outdated but it still should work for you.

Moreover, @JeremyW answer should work, can you be more specific on the error ?

EDIT : " error: TypeError: Object(...) is not a function"

If you face this error, this is likely a compatibility problem with rxjs 5, you may try with rxjs 6.

check this post :
[Angular2 fire listen to node changes throws an error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50700601/angular2-fire-listen-to-node-changes-throws-an-error/51203536#51203536)