# Ionic3 app works in browser but does not work in android

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, ionic3

I have an app which works fine in browser mode (ionic serve) but when I try it with Android (cordova) a function of it does not work.

As in the image below, I want to get data from firebase database which works in browser (from the right side) but not in android (left side of image). It is the same code. What can be the problem ? When I inspect it: **Error: typescript error: Object() is not a function**

[image]

Comment: are u using any package??

Comment: @UnluckyAj I use different plugins. I am new to ionic, I dont know what you mean sorry

Comment: please refer to ionicframework.com/docs/.

Comment: If you are using Angularfire2 then that library has a compatibility issue with RxJS.
refer below answer.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51126463/angularfiredatabase-does-not-retrieve-data/51285524#51285524